# Hashmap Key Value Pair in Language nam and code

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, translate, google-translation-api

I am creating a translator app in which user need to choose the target language if suppose he choose French from the spinner then value for the FRENCH should be *'fr'* so i can pass that value in url. I have created a spinner and assigned languages from array adapter but I want to use it's short form like for *French* the value should be *fr* how can I achieve that?

"French","fr"
"Arabic", "ar"
"English", "en"

my app shows the language list KEY and app crahes when translate button is pressed
here is my code, what next

Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

```
    Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
    flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
    flanguages.put("English", "en");
    flanguages.put("French", "fr");
    flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
    flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
    flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: here is my updated spinner code. now i want to know how to pass the language value code to url. if user chose Arabic, "ar" should be pass to url for translation. how can i pass the value to url.

Comment: Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
        flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
        flanguages.put("English", "en");
        flanguages.put("French", "fr");
        flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
        flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
        flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());


     i have my spinner working fine

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which essential text is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.

Comment: @RyanM see my edited question. pls help, i want to chose the languages to translate. i have set up map and add the key to my spinner, how will i send it to url for translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do is to create a LanguageItem Class.

```
class LanguageItem{
    String language;
    String isoCode;

    override String toString(){
      return language;
   }
}
```

Use this class to add your language and its iso code. Put it in ArrayList and show it in spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<LanguageItem> adapter = new ArrayAdpter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraylist)
```

Now onItemSelected you can easily get selected LanguageItem with the position.